# Discard symbols from package

Tags: symbols

I want to use a single symbol from the `MnSymbol` package, `\nuparrow` (I can't find that symbol anywhere else).  But if I use it, then it upsets the symbols in the rest of the document, which I am happy with.

Comment: ... which you are _not_ happy with?

Comment: @HendrikVogt, I believe "which I am happy with" modifies "the rest of the document," not "it upsets."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can setup a single symbol like this (the code is extracted from mnsymbol. It will not clash if you load the package too):

```
\documentclass{article}



\DeclareFontFamily{U}  {MnSymbolB}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolB}{m}{n}{
    <-6>  MnSymbolB5
   <6-7>  MnSymbolB6
   <7-8>  MnSymbolB7
   <8-9>  MnSymbolB8
   <9-10> MnSymbolB9
  <10-12> MnSymbolB10
  <12->   MnSymbolB12}{}

\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolB}{b}{n}{
    <-6>  MnSymbolB-Bold5
   <6-7>  MnSymbolB-Bold6
   <7-8>  MnSymbolB-Bold7
   <8-9>  MnSymbolB-Bold8
   <9-10> MnSymbolB-Bold9
  <10-12> MnSymbolB-Bold10
  <12->   MnSymbolB-Bold12}{}

\DeclareSymbolFont{MnSyB}         {U}  {MnSymbolB}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{MnSyB}       {bold}{U}  {MnSymbolB}{b}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\nuparrow}{\mathrel}{MnSyB}{1}

\begin{document}
$\nuparrow$

\mathversion{bold}

$\nuparrow$
\end{document}
```

Comment: excellent! Thanks. What exactly am I looking at, and where can I learn more about this code?

Comment: (there's also an explanation in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36088/250119 .)

Answer (score 4):

The `mathtools` package also defines it by rotating and mirroring an existing symbol. Note that `MnSymbol` symbols often does not mix well with others.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[
A \nuparrow B
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  Latex complains that \nuparrow is undefined?

Comment: And you used BOTH packages in this example, and have a fully updated LaTeX installation

Comment: yes.  I have texlive installed on Fedora.  I copied your code verbatim; both packages are installed.

Comment: I have found a sort of hack using the xy package.  I don't know any metafont but I can't imagine it's that hard to define an upward arrow with a line through it?

Comment: Which mathtools version? Note that several Linux dists. are very slow at updating their LaTeX. This is why I always use the one from TUG, an update it manually with the build in manager. That was I KNOW I have the latest versions, I don't have to wait for some lazy dist. manager.

Answer (score 4):

Just to explain Ulrike's Meta Font code a bit and where I think it comes from.

The Declare{Font,Symbol}* commands load the MetaFont files used to define the mathematical symbol.  So, for example, MnSymbolB corresponds to the file located at `/usr/share/texmf/fonts/source/public/MnSymbol/MnSymbolB.mf` on my Fedora box.  It includes the file `Sym-Arrows.mf`, in the same folder.  And defines the boolean value `negated` to be true.  Looking at the `Sym-Arrows.mf` file, we see that boolean used to determine whether the arrow is crossed out or not.  The final argument (call it n) is 1 in

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\nuparrow}{\mathrel}{MnSyB}{1}
```

is the first symbol defined in Sym-Arrows.mf.  It is a single arrow with angle alpha = 0 (pointing upward) which is crossed out (because `negated = true`).  If n=2 then the angle would be 90, since that's the second element in the `for` list.  This list continues between successive `for`s.  So if I take n=9 then I get a double negated arrow pointing upward.