# Importing single symbol from MnSymbol

Tags: fonts, symbols

I wish to use a symbol provided by the package MnSymbol but if I have a `\usepackage{MnSymbol}` in my document then many other symbols change, including even the equals sign (=), which appears much shorter now.

How can I use a package to just get a few particular symbols without having my entire document in the font that the package imposes?

Comment: Very much related: [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font)

Comment: I think there is no explicit relation. The problem occurs very often and so we should provide a more generally answer for MnSymbol.

Comment: Which symbol of the MnSymbol package do you want to use?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: I don't think a good general answer exists. Moreover, `MnSymbol` is a bit different: it doesn't provides `.fd` files, but defines the font families in the `.sty` file. Then we must copy a lot of code from `MnSymbol` to the document.

Answer (score 62):

## Similar questions

It is, my apologies, very difficult to get a symbol from `MnSymbol`. In the old questions,

[Discard symbols from package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12843/disgard-symbols-from-package) (`MnSymbol`)
[The standard \cup vs. the mathabx \cup](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9956/the-standard-cup-vs-the-mathabx-cup) (`mathabx`)
[Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font) (`mathabx`)

some similar technique is used to get a symbol from a package — In fact we just redefine the symbol like the font package do.

## About MnSymbol

However, in `MnSymbol` we must define a more things than other packages, as Ulrike Fischer do in [her answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12847/2674). I'll provide another very similar example from [another site](http://bbs.ctex.org/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=56226):

Before reading the explanations below, you'd better have a look at [`fntguide`](http://www.latex-project.org/guides/fntguide.pdf) document.

Assuming you want `\rightlsquigarrow` from `MnSymbol`, you must check the source code `MnSymbol.sty`, then we have

```
\Decl@Mn@Char\rightlsquigarrow       {MnSyA}{\mathrel}
```

It's awful! We still do not know which the symbol is. In fact `\Decl@Mn@Char` is just `\DeclareMathSymbol` which increase the character number automatically. `\rightlsquigarrow` is the 160th symbol, thus char code is 160. Or you can use `fonttable` package to find the code of the glyph. That's to say, `\rightlsquigarrow` is

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rightlsquigarrow}{\mathrel}{MnSyA}{160}
```

`\mathrel` here means that the symbol is a math binary relation symbol. Other symbols may be `\mathord` (odinary symbol), `\mathop` (operator), `\mathbin` (binary operation), `\mathopen` (open delimiter), `\mathclose` (close delimiter), etc. You can read [`fntguide`](http://www.latex-project.org/guides/fntguide.pdf) for more details of these commands.

But before that, you must define `MnSyA` math family first. Then copy this from `MnSymbol.sty`:

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{MnSyA} {U} {MnSymbolA}{m}{n}
```

For most math font packages, that's enough. But for `MnSymbol`, the font family `MnSymbolA` is also defined in `MnSymbol.sty`, we must copy it to the documents.

```
\DeclareFontFamily{U} {MnSymbolA}{}

\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolA}{m}{n}{
  <-6> MnSymbolA5
  <6-7> MnSymbolA6
  <7-8> MnSymbolA7
  <8-9> MnSymbolA8
  <9-10> MnSymbolA9
  <10-12> MnSymbolA10
  <12-> MnSymbolA12}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolA}{b}{n}{
  <-6> MnSymbolA-Bold5
  <6-7> MnSymbolA-Bold6
  <7-8> MnSymbolA-Bold7
  <8-9> MnSymbolA-Bold8
  <9-10> MnSymbolA-Bold9
  <10-12> MnSymbolA-Bold10
  <12-> MnSymbolA-Bold12}{}
```

Now, if we don't know `\rightlsquigarrow` is actually the 160th symbol, we can use a small test file to check the glyph table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fonttable}
\begin{document}
\fonttable{MnSymbolA10}
\end{document}
```

[image: A picture for fonttable]

After all of this, you know exactly what `\rightlsquigarrow` is, and you can use it as this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareFontFamily{U} {MnSymbolA}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolA}{m}{n}{
  <-6> MnSymbolA5
  <6-7> MnSymbolA6
  <7-8> MnSymbolA7
  <8-9> MnSymbolA8
  <9-10> MnSymbolA9
  <10-12> MnSymbolA10
  <12-> MnSymbolA12}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolA}{b}{n}{
  <-6> MnSymbolA-Bold5
  <6-7> MnSymbolA-Bold6
  <7-8> MnSymbolA-Bold7
  <8-9> MnSymbolA-Bold8
  <9-10> MnSymbolA-Bold9
  <10-12> MnSymbolA-Bold10
  <12-> MnSymbolA-Bold12}{}

\DeclareSymbolFont{MnSyA} {U} {MnSymbolA}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\rightlsquigarrow}{\mathrel}{MnSyA}{160}

\begin{document}

$\rightlsquigarrow$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for a very clear and useful answer! I hope the `MnSybol` would one day be re-written to allow importing single symbols, or not to ruin symbols from other packages.

Comment: Worth clarifying that you might need to use `\mathord` instead of `\mathrel` with `\DeclareMathSymbol` (if the symbol you are importing is not a relational symbol). Otherwise your spacing will go weird.

Comment: @Roly: An arrow is a relation symbol, right?

Comment: Yes, but other symbols aren't usually treated as relation symbols, such as `\medsquare`. When you import them you need to use `\mathord`. (The original question asked about importing arbitrary symbols from MnSymbol.)

Comment: @Roly: There can be `\mathbin`, `\mathop`, `\mathopen`, `\mathclose`, and `\mathpunct` too. What we do is to copy the definition from the font package, the font designer defines what the symbol should be.

Comment: @LeoLiu Indeed. Your answer is very useful, but made even more so by this clarification. Otherwise one might think one can copy your solution modulo `MnSy[A|B|C|...]` and the character codes themselves, as I did, before I spotted that one also needs to consider which of `\mathbin`, `\mathop`, `\mathopen`, `\mathclose`, and `\mathpunct` one needs to pass to `\DeclareMathSymbol`.

Comment: @Roly: That's why I suggested the OP reading `fntguide` at the beginning. Anyway, I add some more explanation for that.

Comment: There's unfortunately a broken [link](http://www.latex-project.org/guides/fntguide.pdf) to the `fntguide` document.