# What is the easiest way to circumvent TeX's restriction on 16 math fonts?

Tags: fonts, math-mode

I need to use math symbols from different fonts, exceeding the count of 16. What is the easiest way to adapt my setup to be able to use more math fonts?

I'm looking for either of the following:

- hacks that let me cheat around the restriction
- another setup that is likely to be most compatible with what I'm currently using, namely `pdflatex`

I know that there are systems/engines such as LuaTeX and XeTeX (both allowing way more than 16 math fonts), but I'm really looking for something that is as conservative as possible an extension of LaTeX. The reason is that I'm using a lot of packages written for LaTeX, and switching over to something like XeTeX for my current project is likely to break things in subtle ways.

If the answer is "there is no way", that's also okay.

*Here is a minimal example of uncompilable code:*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for the \mspace command and other things (necessity of this package not demonstrated in this minimal example)
\usepackage{dsfont} % for the \mathds command
\usepackage{txfonts} % for \coloneqq; also: if I omit this line, I get an error message saying that "Command \lhd not provided in base LaTeX2e" (I need \lhd)
\usepackage[only,llbracket,rrbracket,llparenthesis,rrparenthesis]{stmaryrd} % imports: [| |] (| |)
\usepackage[mathb]{mathabx} % for \sqbullet and \blackdiamond

% for \lcurvearrowdown:
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{MnSymbolA}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolA}{m}{n}{
  <-6> MnSymbolA5
  <6-7> MnSymbolA6
  <7-8> MnSymbolA7
  <8-9> MnSymbolA8
  <9-10> MnSymbolA9
  <10-12> MnSymbolA10
  <12-> MnSymbolA12}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolA}{b}{n}{
  <-6> MnSymbolA-Bold5
  <6-7> MnSymbolA-Bold6
  <7-8> MnSymbolA-Bold7
  <8-9> MnSymbolA-Bold8
  <9-10> MnSymbolA-Bold9
  <10-12> MnSymbolA-Bold10
  <12-> MnSymbolA-Bold12}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{MnSyA}{U}{MnSymbolA}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\lcurvearrowdown}{\mathrel}{MnSyA}{187}

% for \sqsubseteq and \nsqsubseteq; I don't like the appearance of these symbols from txfonts, so I am using the respective MnSymbol ones, except I'm naming them \sqeq and \nsqeq
% THIS IS THE CODE BLOCK THAT FIRST MADE MY FILE UNCOMPILABLE WHEN I ADDED IT
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{MnSymbolD}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolD}{m}{n}{
    <-6>  MnSymbolD5
   <6-7>  MnSymbolD6
   <7-8>  MnSymbolD7
   <8-9>  MnSymbolD8
   <9-10> MnSymbolD9
  <10-12> MnSymbolD10
  <12->   MnSymbolD12}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolD}{b}{n}{
    <-6>  MnSymbolD-Bold5
   <6-7>  MnSymbolD-Bold6
   <7-8>  MnSymbolD-Bold7
   <8-9>  MnSymbolD-Bold8
   <9-10> MnSymbolD-Bold9
  <10-12> MnSymbolD-Bold10
  <12->   MnSymbolD-Bold12}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{MnSyD}{U}{MnSymbolD}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sqeq}{\mathrel}{MnSyD}{90}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\nsqeq}{\mathrel}{MnSyD}{210}

\begin{document}

\( \mathds{N} \) % WITHOUT THIS LINE, THE CODE COMPILES

\( \coloneqq \) % this line is not required to get a minimal example of uncompilable code, but I need this symbol

\( \llbracket,\rrbracket,\llparenthesis,\rrparenthesis \) % this line is not required to get a minimal example of uncompilable code, but I need these symbols

\( \sqbullet, \blackdiamond \) % this line is not required to get a minimal example of uncompilable code, but I need these symbols

\( \lcurvearrowdown \) % this line is not required to get a minimal example of uncompilable code, but I need this symbol

\( a \sqeq b \nsqeq c \) % this line is not required to get a minimal example of uncompilable code, but I need these symbols

\( \mathit{abc} \) % WITHOUT THIS LINE, THE CODE COMPILES

\( \mathsf{a} \) % WITHOUT THIS LINE, THE CODE COMPILES

\end{document}
```

*(I know this is an arbitrary example, but I think it serves the purpose of illustrating the issue.)*

Comment: There is no way. If you define a math alphabet for a few symbols there's the possibility to avoid allocating one, but if the usage is extensive, the overhead would be noticeable.

Comment: do you need more than 16 fonts _in one expression_ ? because it is possible (if tiresome) to shuffle the assignments so that each expression has a different set of 16 fonts

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I only need a couple per expression, though as a casual user I do not exactly know which mathfonts I am using for which symbols. I am currently at the limit, having loaded many necessary packages, and when I follow the advice [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36006/how-can-i-use-a-symbol-provided-by-a-package-without-changing-the-entire-mathema) to load the `\sqsubseteq` and `\nsqsubseteq` symbols from the MnSymbolD font, I get the error `Too many math alphabets used in version normal.`

Comment: As always questions are _much_ easier to answer if the question contains a complete (small) working (or not) document. Please edit the question with a document with the minimal number of packages you have loaded to get this error and a couple of math expressions you need to typeset. 16 is in most cases more than enough (I don't think I have had this error on a real as opposed to test) document more than a couple of times in 25 years of tex use.

Comment: It seems likely you are over-defining the sets eg if you load mathtime and ams font sets you use up twice as many slots but get essentially no more symbols as they define the same symbols (with different appearance as different font) but you don't want _both_ version of \sum (say) in the same document.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have added a minimal example.

Comment: @user14996 You are in the situation described by Peter Breitfeld: don't allocate a math symbol font just for a few symbols.

Comment: @egreg I assume you are referring to the two blocks of code enabling the 3 MnSymbol symbols? Okay, I'll try right now; thanks for your advice.

Comment: For the first symbol, for instance, remove `\DeclareSymbolFont{MnSyA}{U}{MnSymbolA}{m}{n}` and instead of `\DeclareMathSymbol{\lcurvearrowdown}{\mathrel}{MnSyA}{187}` say `\newcommand{\lcurvedarrowdown}{\mathrel{\text{\usefont{U}{MnSymbolA}{m}{n}\symbol{187}}}}`

Comment: @egreg Gotcha, thanks. (I first didn't notice that Peter Breitfeld was the one who wrote an answer and that you were referring to that answer.)

Comment: @egreg Very minor correction to your comment: `\lcurvedarrowdown` -> `\lcurvearrowdown`

Comment: @user14996 Right. Keep also in mind Khaled Hosny's comment, though; but if you need only symbols such as this one (and the other you have in your example), there should be no problem. There would be for symbols such as summation or integral that require different treatment.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Great, I consider this problem solved, *except* now I'm curious about the shuffling of assignments David Carlisle mentioned.

Comment: @user14996 see my answer where I modify the normal mathversion to lose mathtt and allow the symbol fonts to be loaded instead. You can if necessary work harder and save lots of different versions of the normal mathversion with different font assignments and then switch between them for different expressions. This is basically how \boldmath works

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't need the whole font, but only some glyphs you can call them directly with usefont. This doesn't increase the number of math fonts:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathpazo, 
  amsmath}               %to use \text
\newcommand{\cmvarpi}{\text{\usefont{OML}{cmr}{m}{it}\symbol{36}}}
\begin{document}
  \LARGE
  $x=\varpi=\cmvarpi=y$
\end{document}
```

[image: equation]

Comment: But this will break accent and sub/superscript positing of those symbols, can't be used with big operators and so on, so it is of very limited utility.

Answer (score 9):

There is no way. Even switching to engines that allow more than 16 families will not automatically help you, because the format of `\mathchar` (and similar math commands) can’t handle more than 16 families, so you will need to also switch to extended math commands (e.g. using `unicode-math` package).

Answer (score 6):

Here I show how one can remove a predefined math alphabet; one can `\UndeclareMathAlphabet{\mathtt}`, for instance, thus saving one of them. Unfortunately, an approach with `regexpatch` is difficult for various reasons.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,l3regex}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\UndeclareMathAlphabet}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl {\exp_not:N \install@mathalphabet \exp_not:c {\cs_to_str:N #1~}}
  \regex_replace_once:nnNT { \u{l_tmpa_tl} \cB. \c[^BE].* \cE. } {} \mv@normal { \addtocounter{mv@normal}{-1} }
  \regex_replace_once:nnNT { \u{l_tmpa_tl} \cB. \c[^BE].* \cE. } {} \mv@bold { \addtocounter{mv@bold}{-1} }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\@onlypreamble\UndeclareMathAlphabet
\makeatother

\typeout{\expandafter\meaning\csname mv@normal\endcsname}
\typeout{\expandafter\meaning\csname mv@bold\endcsname}
\UndeclareMathAlphabet{\mathtt}
\typeout{\expandafter\meaning\csname mv@normal\endcsname}
\typeout{\expandafter\meaning\csname mv@bold\endcsname}
\UndeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsf}
\typeout{\expandafter\meaning\csname mv@normal\endcsname}
\typeout{\expandafter\meaning\csname mv@bold\endcsname}
```

The output is

```
macro:->\getanddefine@fonts \symoperators \OT1/cmr/m/n \getanddefine@fonts \sym
letters \OML/cmm/m/it \getanddefine@fonts \symsymbols \OMS/cmsy/m/n \getanddefi
ne@fonts \symlargesymbols \OMX/cmex/m/n \install@mathalphabet \mathbf  {\select
@group \mathbf  \M@OT1 \OT1/cmr/bx/n }\install@mathalphabet \mathsf  {\select@g
roup \mathsf  \M@OT1 \OT1/cmss/m/n }\install@mathalphabet \mathit  {\select@gro
up \mathit  \M@OT1 \OT1/cmr/m/it }\install@mathalphabet \mathtt  {\select@group
 \mathtt  \M@OT1 \OT1/cmtt/m/n }
macro:->\getanddefine@fonts \symoperators \OT1/cmr/bx/n \getanddefine@fonts \sy
mletters \OML/cmm/b/it \getanddefine@fonts \symsymbols \OMS/cmsy/b/n \getanddef
ine@fonts \symlargesymbols \OMX/cmex/m/n \install@mathalphabet \mathbf  {\selec
t@group \mathbf  \M@OT1 \OT1/cmr/bx/n }\install@mathalphabet \mathsf  {\select@
group \mathsf  \M@OT1 \OT1/cmss/bx/n }\install@mathalphabet \mathit  {\select@g
roup \mathit  \M@OT1 \OT1/cmr/bx/it }\install@mathalphabet \mathtt  {\select@gr
oup \mathtt  \M@OT1 \OT1/cmtt/m/n }
macro:->\getanddefine@fonts \symoperators \OT1/cmr/m/n \getanddefine@fonts \sym
letters \OML/cmm/m/it \getanddefine@fonts \symsymbols \OMS/cmsy/m/n \getanddefi
ne@fonts \symlargesymbols \OMX/cmex/m/n \install@mathalphabet \mathbf  {\select
@group \mathbf  \M@OT1 \OT1/cmr/bx/n }\install@mathalphabet \mathsf  {\select@g
roup \mathsf  \M@OT1 \OT1/cmss/m/n }\install@mathalphabet \mathit  {\select@gro
up \mathit  \M@OT1 \OT1/cmr/m/it }
macro:->\getanddefine@fonts \symoperators \OT1/cmr/bx/n \getanddefine@fonts \sy
mletters \OML/cmm/b/it \getanddefine@fonts \symsymbols \OMS/cmsy/b/n \getanddef
ine@fonts \symlargesymbols \OMX/cmex/m/n \install@mathalphabet \mathbf  {\selec
t@group \mathbf  \M@OT1 \OT1/cmr/bx/n }\install@mathalphabet \mathsf  {\select@
group \mathsf  \M@OT1 \OT1/cmss/bx/n }\install@mathalphabet \mathit  {\select@g
roup \mathit  \M@OT1 \OT1/cmr/bx/it }
macro:->\getanddefine@fonts \symoperators \OT1/cmr/m/n \getanddefine@fonts \sym
letters \OML/cmm/m/it \getanddefine@fonts \symsymbols \OMS/cmsy/m/n \getanddefi
ne@fonts \symlargesymbols \OMX/cmex/m/n \install@mathalphabet \mathbf  {\select
@group \mathbf  \M@OT1 \OT1/cmr/bx/n }\install@mathalphabet \mathit  {\select@g
roup \mathit  \M@OT1 \OT1/cmr/m/it }
macro:->\getanddefine@fonts \symoperators \OT1/cmr/bx/n \getanddefine@fonts \sy
mletters \OML/cmm/b/it \getanddefine@fonts \symsymbols \OMS/cmsy/b/n \getanddef
ine@fonts \symlargesymbols \OMX/cmex/m/n \install@mathalphabet \mathbf  {\selec
t@group \mathbf  \M@OT1 \OT1/cmr/bx/n }\install@mathalphabet \mathit  {\select@
group \mathit  \M@OT1 \OT1/cmr/bx/it }
```

which shows that both `\mathtt` and `\mathsf` have been removed successfully.

Answer (score 3):

I deleted my first answer. It is possible to modify LaTeX's internal math structures, but as you noted I hot it wrong (and haven't time to fix at present) @egreg has a more robust version.

However to return to the theme of using text fonts to avoid using up the 16 math font slots. perhaps the fonts for which the lack of math setup are the *math alphabets* rather than the symbol fonts. If you add

```
 \def\mathsf#1{\text{\textsf{#1}}}
```

to your preamble then `\mathsf` will use the same font as before but via a nested text box, and your file processes without error.

Comment: Will the result be similar to using to using a "proper" math font though?

Comment: the font will be identical as will the horizontal spacing, what you mostly lose is positioning of accents and subscripts as `\dot{\mathsf{a}}` or `\mathsf{a}_1` can use the font metric information to adjust the positioning but after the redefinition they are being applied to a box like difference between `\mathrm{a}_1` and `\mbox{a}_1`. but in many documents \mathsf or \mathtt just used for identifiers only occasionaly used with scripts

Comment: I think this is a fantastic solution, thank you!