# Strange integral symbol

Tags: symbols

I'm getting the following rendering of my \int command inside equation environment

This is in my opinion really ugly! I want the usual one back!

[image]

Do you have any idea about what happened to my latex environment?

Comment: I swear I didn't do it. In other words, is there any possibility for us to know what happened on your computer? Probably you have used a package that changes the math fonts. Remove the packages one by one and you'll find it.

Comment: It looks like you've loaded the `MnSymbol` package. Don't.

Comment: Oh thanks guys! I exactly load the MnSymbol package, but I didn't find it, because I put it in a weird place in my document. The mystery is solved! Write down an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: This question has surely helped future visitors and should not be closed.

Answer (score 18):

That integral symbol shape is peculiar of the MnSymbol math fonts, which were designed to accompany Minion. I too find it not particularly appealing, but it's a matter of opinion.

Quite probably you have

```
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
```

in your document. Somebody, from time to time, suggests to load the package (and the MnSymbol fonts) because it provides many symbols that are not found in standard packages such as `amssymb`. This is wrong, in my opinion, because it changes *all* math symbols with its own and they generally don't match the main text font.

For using one or more of the provided symbols, see [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font) or [Importing single symbol from MnSymbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36006/how-can-i-use-a-symbol-provided-by-a-package-without-changing-the-entire-mathema)