# Creating text symbols with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, symbols

I seem to recall a macro which was used to create symbols which could be inserted into text, but cannot remember the name nor find it using search.

I could do it myself easy enough

```
\newcommand{\reddot}{\tikz{\fill[red] (0,0) circle (4pt);}}
```

but don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: What symbols in specific?

Comment: Don't know.  I just checked the Comprehensive List of LaTeX Math Symbols.  (Found \checkmark and \bigstar.)  Symbols I can use in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149942/special-table-with-diagonal-lines/150222#150222

Comment: I think this answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/103438/1952 can help you. It explains how to insert `plotmarks` in regular text.

Comment: Two more useful references: [how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-alphabet](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-alphabet), [how-to-write-checkmark-in-latex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132783/how-to-write-checkmark-in-latex)

Comment: It seems my memory is in error.  The tikzsymbol manual did give me some ideas about adding optional arguments.

Answer (score 5):

Well for "Symbols" there is [`tikzsymbols`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzsymbols):

You can use TikZ as well:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{{\scriptsize\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle, draw, inner sep=1pt, align=center] (char) {#1};}}}
\usepackage{tikzsymbols}
\begin{document}

 Something like that \circled{E} or like {%
            \protect\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.17]
               \protect\draw (0,0) -- (.5,1);
               \protect\draw (.5,1) -- (1.5,1);
               \protect\draw (1.5,1) -- (1,0);
               \protect\draw (1,0) -- (0,0);
            \protect\end{tikzpicture}%
            }% 
\,that? Or like that \tikzsymbolsuse{Smiley}[]?

\end{document}
```

Comment: The existing tikzsymbol package symbol set is not that useful.

Comment: Nice solution! Mind that such [_fragile_ macros can be problematic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56081/84434) inside a `\caption`, so call your `\newcommand` with `\protect`.

Comment: This solution doesn't respect the local change of font size via `\Large` for example.