# Typing Following notation in Latex

Tags: math-mode, symbols, math-operators

I need to generate following notation in LaTeX.

It's used in differential geometry to denote vector fields.

I can't find documentation and detexify is not helpful either.

[image]

Comment: [`MnSymbol`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mnsymbol) provides `\vertbowtie`...

Comment: Try also `\newcommand{\vectfield}{\mathrel{\text{\scalebox{0.85}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\vartriangleright\mkern-4mu\vartriangleleft$}}}}}`. Requires `graphicx`, `amsmath` and `amssymb`. Adjust 0.85 to your needs.

Comment: @Werner -- not a duplicate, i think, since it's not in detexify.  but the cited question could have material added to offer a few more strategies for searching, e.g., in the comprehensive symbols list, for example, looking for a rotated or mirrored version by name (helps if the name is known).  i also note that unicode has this symbol (U+29D6) identified as "hourglass", but that name isn't in either detexify or the comprehensive list; should be in the stix fonts (though the general documentation hasn't caught up).

Comment: @barbarabeeton: It's in the [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf), hence my vote-to-close.

Comment: @Werner -- what do you think of the suggestion to add some more information about search strategies to the question you cited?  as it stands, although i agree it's in the comprehensive list, there's no really effective way to find it if you don't already know its name, and the name used is, while plausible, not a "standard" name.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: That's an often-debated concern that I have, similar to the question about using a dictionary for spelling purposes; if you want to look up/knkow the spelling of a word, you need to know how to spell it to find it. Hmmm. I guess some suggestions to search strategies might help (and perhaps also reference *this* post).

Comment: @Werner -- good addition.  thanks.  i now agree that the situation in this question is covered there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(As Werner pointed out before me) It's in the MnSymbol package as `\vertbowtie`.  And as Torbjorn T. pointed out, one does not, in general, want to get all the MnSymbols loaded, as they overwrite a lot of default stuff.  Using the pointer that Torbjorn provided ([Importing single symbol from MnSymbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36006/how-can-i-use-a-symbol-provided-by-a-package-without-changing-the-entire-mathema/)), I was able to look at MnSymbol.dtx on CTAN (http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/mnsymbol/tex/MnSymbol.dtx) to find that `\vertbowtie` was defined as

```
\Decl@Mn@Char\vertbowtie             {MnSyC}{\mathbin}
```

I was also able to use the `fonttable` package to display the MnSymbolC font table to determine that the `\vertbowtie` was symbol 39.  And armed with that information, I was able to extract just that symbol as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareFontFamily{U} {MnSymbolC}{}

\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolC}{m}{n}{
  <-6> MnSymbolC5
  <6-7> MnSymbolC6
  <7-8> MnSymbolC7
  <8-9> MnSymbolC8
  <9-10> MnSymbolC9
  <10-12> MnSymbolC10
  <12-> MnSymbolC12}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolC}{b}{n}{
  <-6> MnSymbolC-Bold5
  <6-7> MnSymbolC-Bold6
  <7-8> MnSymbolC-Bold7
  <8-9> MnSymbolC-Bold8
  <9-10> MnSymbolC-Bold9
  <10-12> MnSymbolC-Bold10
  <12-> MnSymbolC-Bold12}{}

\DeclareSymbolFont{MnSyC} {U} {MnSymbolC}{m}{n}
%\Decl@Mn@Char\vertbowtie             {MnSyC}{\mathbin}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vertbowtie}{\mathbin}{MnSyC}{39}

%\usepackage{fonttable}
\begin{document}
%\fonttable{MnSymbolC10}
$a \vertbowtie b$
\end{document}
```

[image]

For those of us who don't breathe LaTeX fonts, several points were necessary for me to grok, that were not made clear at [Importing single symbol from MnSymbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36006/how-can-i-use-a-symbol-provided-by-a-package-without-changing-the-entire-mathema/).

1) The `\DeclareSymbolFont` macro had to come before the `\DeclareMathSymbol`, so that the name `MnSyC` was recognized.

2) The name `\mathbin` in the `\DeclareMathSymbol` macro must match the last argument of `\Decl@Mn@Char`, as found in the font's sty/dtx file.

3) The macro `\Decl@Mn@Char` is not part of the solution, but rather one must find it in the dtx file in order to obtain the font family (`MnSyC`) and the "category" (`\mathbin`).  [sorry for the use of imprecise terminology...I'm sure these things have official names].

Of course, no Segletes solution would be complete without an alternate `stackengine` solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\def\myvertbowtie{\mathrel{\stackon[0pt]{\def\stacktype{L}%
    \stackon[0pt]{\sffamily x}{\rule{1ex}{.1ex}}}{\rule{1ex}{.1ex}}}}
\parskip 1em
\begin{document}
\(  a \myvertbowtie b \)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With regard to MnSymbol it should be noted that it will change a lot (all?) of the various mathematical symbols. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36006/how-can-i-use-a-symbol-provided-by-a-package-without-changing-the-entire-mathema/ and linked questions, that deal with using just a single symbol from such a package.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.  Thanks for the pointer.  I hopefully used it to provide more value to my solution.