# Creating a custom math symbol from scratch

Tags: symbols

I want to use a special symbol from the [Com­pre­hen­sive LaTeX Sym­bol List](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) called `\diamondtimes`. Unfortunately, when I include the [`MnSymbol`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/mnsymbol/MnSymbol.pdf) package that provides this symbol, it also affects how other things look like. Since I need only this single symbol, is there any way to **design it from scratch** so that I don't have to include any extra packages?

Maybe it can be build by adding something on top of the standard `\diamond` symbol? In fact, I want the diamond produced by `\diamondtimes` to be the same size as `\diamond`, since I plan to use both.

**Update:** Since it has such a simple shape, I would prefer to make it from scratch (or put something on top of `\diamond`). Here is the original code from [Sym-Geometric.mf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/mnsymbol/source/Sym-Geometric.mf):

```
beginoperator(med_op_size#, 1); "medium diamond times";
  pickup rule_pen;
  r := w/2 - side_bearing;
  draw square(centre, r / sqrt(2), 45);
  draw (centre + sqrt .5 * r * dir  45) -- (centre + sqrt .5 * r * dir 225);
  draw (centre + sqrt .5 * r * dir 135) -- (centre + sqrt .5 * r * dir 315);
endchar;
```

What language is this in and can I just reuse this somehow?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132453/typing-following-notation-in-latex/132456#132456 for how to get a MNSymbol into your font

Comment: I just found this post: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36006/how-can-i-use-a-symbol-provided-by-a-package-without-changing-the-entire-mathema/ and I'm trying to follow the instructions.

Comment: BTW: the "language" is MetaFont

Comment: The language is indeed metafont, but this extract contains commands that are not in standard metafont. Presumably these are macros defined in some file in the `MnSymbol` package. However, it is easy to deduce what is going on if one knows metafont: A square is drawn, rotated 45 degrees, and then the two crossing lines are drawn.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rotate `\boxplus` by 45 degrees:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath,amssymb}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\diamondtimes}{%
  \mathbin{\text{\rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{$\boxplus$}}}%
}

\begin{document}
$a\diamondtimes b$

$a\times b$
\end{document}
```

[image]

For a smaller version and an empty diamond (note that `\diamond` already exists, but gives a much smaller symbol):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath,amssymb}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\diamondtimes}{%
  \mathbin{\text{\scalebox{.75}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{$\boxplus$}}}}%
}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\bdiamond}{%
  \mathbin{\text{\scalebox{.75}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{$\Box$}}}}%
}
\begin{document}
$a\diamondtimes b$

$a\bdiamond b$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to make it a bit smaller and also to have a `\diamond` symbol of the same size?

Comment: A beautiful solution. But might it not be better to define the new symbol once, store it in a box register (or several, using `\mathchoice` for various sizes) and then `\copy` the box each time the symbol is used?

Comment: @jvarilly: I'm not familiar with these commands. Could you give some pointer on how to use them?

Comment: @jvarilly With the box approach the symbol wouldn't change size according to `\small`, `\footnotesize` and the like.

Answer (score 5):

Mimicing the procedure depicted at [Typing Following notation in Latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132453/typing-following-notation-in-latex/132456#132456), I was able to determine that `\diamondtimes` was part of MnSymbolC font set.  Then, using the `fonttable` package (uncomment 2 lines in MWE), I found the symbol number to be 125.  Then, I just changed the name and numbers  from that example to get this one.

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareFontFamily{U} {MnSymbolC}{}

\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolC}{m}{n}{
  <-6> MnSymbolC5
  <6-7> MnSymbolC6
  <7-8> MnSymbolC7
  <8-9> MnSymbolC8
  <9-10> MnSymbolC9
  <10-12> MnSymbolC10
  <12-> MnSymbolC12}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolC}{b}{n}{
  <-6> MnSymbolC-Bold5
  <6-7> MnSymbolC-Bold6
  <7-8> MnSymbolC-Bold7
  <8-9> MnSymbolC-Bold8
  <9-10> MnSymbolC-Bold9
  <10-12> MnSymbolC-Bold10
  <12-> MnSymbolC-Bold12}{}

\DeclareSymbolFont{MnSyC} {U} {MnSymbolC}{m}{n}
%\Decl@Mn@Char\diamondtimes             {MnSyC}{\mathbin}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\diamondtimes}{\mathbin}{MnSyC}{125}

%\usepackage{fonttable}
\begin{document}
%\fonttable{MnSymbolC10}
$a \diamondtimes b$
\end{document}
```

[image]