# Using a single symbol from an MnSymb package

Tags: symbols, packages, incompatibility

I often face the following problem: I need just a single symbol from a package (currently `\equalclosed` from `MnSymbol`), however loading the whole package causes certain problems with already loaded ones (ams packages in my case). As far as I understood from answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/174814/3260), there is no general solution for this problem. In my particular case, is there a ny short way to use `\equalclosed` or shall I study the structure of the MnSymbol package?

Comment: Does [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/) help?

Comment: This answer, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132453/typing-following-notation-in-latex/132456#132456, also speaks directly to MnSymbol import.

Answer (score 2):

Using the exact technique I employed at [Typing Following notation in Latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132453/typing-following-notation-in-latex/132456#132456).  One only has to uncomment the two `fonttable` lines in my MWE to ascertain that `\equalclosed` was symbol 221 of `MnSyC`.  At that point, changing the pointer, the glphy macro, and the `mathbin` to `mathrel` was all that was needed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareFontFamily{U} {MnSymbolC}{}

\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolC}{m}{n}{
  <-6> MnSymbolC5
  <6-7> MnSymbolC6
  <7-8> MnSymbolC7
  <8-9> MnSymbolC8
  <9-10> MnSymbolC9
  <10-12> MnSymbolC10
  <12-> MnSymbolC12}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolC}{b}{n}{
  <-6> MnSymbolC-Bold5
  <6-7> MnSymbolC-Bold6
  <7-8> MnSymbolC-Bold7
  <8-9> MnSymbolC-Bold8
  <9-10> MnSymbolC-Bold9
  <10-12> MnSymbolC-Bold10
  <12-> MnSymbolC-Bold12}{}

\DeclareSymbolFont{MnSyC} {U} {MnSymbolC}{m}{n}
%\Decl@Mn@Char\equalclosed             {MnSyC}{\mathrel}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\equalclosed}{\mathrel}{MnSyC}{221}

%\usepackage{fonttable}
\begin{document}
%\fonttable{MnSymbolC10}
$a \equalclosed b$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but it still brings the error "too many alphabets". Original document does compile with no problems.