# Bad subscript spacing with `\mathchoice`

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I followed advice from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132453/typing-following-notation-in-latex/132456#132456) to add a symbol from MnSymbol to my document, and while the symbol appears the spacing is bad. In fact I have to use `\mathchoice` to get different integrals in text mode and in display mode, so I need `\mathchoice` but the spacing is bad. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\DeclareFontFamily{U} {MnSymbolF}{}

\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolF}{m}{n}{
  <-6> MnSymbolF5
  <6-7> MnSymbolF6
  <7-8> MnSymbolF7
  <8-9> MnSymbolF8
  <9-10> MnSymbolF9
  <10-12> MnSymbolF10
  <12-> MnSymbolF12}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolF}{b}{n}{
  <-6> MnSymbolF-Bold5
  <6-7> MnSymbolF-Bold6
  <7-8> MnSymbolF-Bold7
  <8-9> MnSymbolF-Bold8
  <9-10> MnSymbolF-Bold9
  <10-12> MnSymbolF-Bold10
  <12-> MnSymbolF-Bold12}{}

\DeclareSymbolFont{MnSyF} {U} {MnSymbolF}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\tstrokedint}{\mathbin}{MnSyF}{"60}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\dstrokedint}{\mathbin}{MnSyF}{"61}

\def\strokedint{\mathchoice{\dstrokedint}{\tstrokedint}{\tstrokedint}{\tstrokedint}}

\begin{document}

$\strokedint_D$ $\tstrokedint_D$ $\dstrokedint_D$

$$\strokedint_D$$

\end{document}
```

and here is the output:

[image]

The red arrows show the bad spacing (with `\mathchoice`) and the green arrows show the correct spacing (accessing the symbol directly, without `\mathchoice`).

Does somebody know how to have both `\mathchoice` and correct spacing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare it as `\mathop` the larger size will be found via the font metrics and you don't need `\mathchoice`

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\DeclareFontFamily{U} {MnSymbolF}{}

\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolF}{m}{n}{
  <-6> MnSymbolF5
  <6-7> MnSymbolF6
  <7-8> MnSymbolF7
  <8-9> MnSymbolF8
  <9-10> MnSymbolF9
  <10-12> MnSymbolF10
  <12-> MnSymbolF12}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolF}{b}{n}{
  <-6> MnSymbolF-Bold5
  <6-7> MnSymbolF-Bold6
  <7-8> MnSymbolF-Bold7
  <8-9> MnSymbolF-Bold8
  <9-10> MnSymbolF-Bold9
  <10-12> MnSymbolF-Bold10
  <12-> MnSymbolF-Bold12}{}

\DeclareSymbolFont{MnSyF} {U} {MnSymbolF}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\strokedintop}{\mathop}{MnSyF}{"60}

\def\strokedint{\strokedintop\nolimits}


\begin{document}

$\strokedint_D$ $\strokedint_D$ $\displaystyle\strokedint_D$

$$\strokedint_D$$

\end{document}
```

Comment: See [Why is `\[` … `\]` preferable to `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5764) :)

Comment: yes but I decided to concentrate on the issue at hand, that post does have an excellent answer though:-)

Comment: Thank you so much David, for the $\infty$-th time! Does this macro presuppose that the display-stye size comes directly after the text-style size?

Comment: @yannis  no it's like ligatures or `\left\right` delimiters, the tex side has no knowledge  a different glyph is used, they are chained together in the tfm tables, so the second glyph can be anywhere in the encoding

Comment: Thanks. Shame on me, the information is in my book, page 626. But that was 20 years ago…