# How can I use curly braces provided by YandY Mathtime in a MathtimePro2 doc?

Tags: braces, mtpro, times

I'm using MathTimePro2 as my math fonts in my documents, so how can I replace curly braces such as `\lbrace`, `\rbrace`, `\underbrace`, `\{`, `\}` etc provided by MTP2 to ones given by YandY MathTime?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since you appear to have the [MathTime Professional II](http://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html) package, I'm not sure what precisely you mean by accessing the (older) `YandY MathTime` curly braces. Would you want to use both the `mtpro2` package and Y&Y's fonts simultaneously?

Note that the instructions `\lbrace`, `\rbrace`, and `\underbrace` you mention in your posting do *not* generate the special curly (curvy?) braces provided by the `mtpro2` package. To access the curvy constructs, you need to use the commands `\lcbrace`, `\rcbrace`, and `\undercbrace`, possibly in connection with a `\LEFTRIGHT` directive.

Comment: I want to use mtpro2, but I dont's like braces give by mtpro2(no matter lbrace or lcbrace...), I just want my equations generated by mtpro2 except those braces, I hope these braces could be locally invoked from YandY mathtime like this [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36006/how-can-i-use-a-symbol-provided-by-a-package-without-changing-the-entire-mathema/36088#36088), as you can see, [this](https://cssdpq.bn1.livefilestore.com/y2pKyub9QST-r2UDmP4ceMKfiw4NiwIuug1QcycZ_S36IwHeydj7Jr1fJfioS2MqnAzW4I2eEsHhF6wM3mVW4tKrZ98UwZJnUG5wmf63JOOFMA/yytimes.png?psid=1) is what I need.

Comment: So what I really need is importing some Symbols from YandY times while usepackage mtpro2, figures from Mico have given above or [this](https://cssdpq.bn1.livefilestore.com/y2plGBzhP6Kdud4MlF_nDG274zPq8Yx_hgUQMKNT4whNNEp0g8ETXsLg-G2qR2hNQ35HQqoHvxzrEh5GhmvcR8KYXAD3sFqQiuSKQL8lOZY8TA/times.png?psid=1) is not the one what I need.

Comment: @PHoward - I've removed the example code and image since you've clarified you're looking for a different solution. Please provide more information about the YandY MathTime package? I was under the impression that Y&Y had ceased operations years ago and that the mathtime fonts they were distributing weren't owned by Y&Y but only licensed to them. I have no idea who owns those fonts and/or how they may be distributed these days.