# Using symbols from the arevmath package without changing the entire mathematics font?

Tags: math-mode, fonts

I know [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36006/how-can-i-use-a-symbol-provided-by-a-package-without-changing-the-entire-mathema) is very similar, but most everything there is centered on `MnSymbol`, but I am trying to use or "obtain" three symbols using the `arevmath` package (I am using `pdfLaTeX` and MiKTeX):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{arevmath}
\begin{document}
The important symbols: $\Sampi, \Qoppa$ and $\stigma$. The problem: $30+40+\phi=0$.
\end{document}
```

produces:
[image]

On the other hand,

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Needed symbols: \texttt{\textbackslash Sampi,\textbackslash Qoppa}, and \texttt{\textbackslash stigma}. No problem: $30+40+\phi=0$.
\end{document}
```

produces:
[image]

Is there a way to get or use these symbols without completely ruining the look of the other mathematical formulas I am trying to use? I tried using `wrisym` as well, but it did not compile. I have looked at a number of other fairly similar questions, but I could not find anything that I could apply directly to the problem I'm currently facing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something like this? This takes a maths alphabet. You can avoid this if necessary but if you want several symbols from the font, it is more straightforward this way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareSymbolFont{extraitalic}      {U}{zavm}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Qoppa}{\mathord}{extraitalic}{161}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\qoppa}{\mathord}{extraitalic}{162}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Stigma}{\mathord}{extraitalic}{167}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Sampi}{\mathord}{extraitalic}{165}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sampi}{\mathord}{extraitalic}{166}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\stigma}{\mathord}{extraitalic}{168}

\begin{document}
The important symbols: $\Sampi, \Qoppa$ and $\stigma$. No problem: $30+40+\phi=0$.
\end{document}
```

[image: mix]

Not necessarily typographically ideal, perhaps, but it does get you those symbols without changing the rest.

## Explanation

I started by just seeing what the package `arev` provided. `arevsymbols.tex` sounded likely so I started there. (Otherwise, I'd have used `grep` to search for one of the commands you mentioned.) I got the definitions of the commands from that file:

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Qoppa}{\mathord}{extraitalic}{161} % uni03D8
\DeclareMathSymbol{\qoppa}{\mathord}{extraitalic}{162} % uni03D9
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Sampi}{\mathord}{extraitalic}{165} % uni03E0
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sampi}{\mathord}{extraitalic}{166} % uni03E1
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Stigma}{\mathord}{extraitalic}{167} % uni03DA
\DeclareMathSymbol{\stigma}{\mathord}{extraitalic}{168} % uni03DB
```

So now I just needed to know what `extraitalic` was. I used `grep` for this on just the `.sty` files:

```
grep extraitalic tex/latex/arev/*.sty
```

This gave me this:

```
tex/latex/arev/arevmath.sty:\DeclareSymbolFont{extraitalic}      {U}{zavm}{m}{it}
tex/latex/arev/arevmath.sty:\ifthenelse{\equal{\var@a}  {true}}{}{\DeclareMathSymbol{a}{\mathalpha}{extraitalic}{139}}
tex/latex/arev/arevmath.sty:\ifthenelse{\equal{\var@i}  {true}}{}{\DeclareMathSymbol{i}{\mathalpha}{extraitalic}{140}
tex/latex/arev/arevmath.sty:                                      \DeclareMathSymbol{\imath}{\mathalpha}{extraitalic}{111}}
tex/latex/arev/arevmath.sty:\ifthenelse{\equal{\var@I}  {true}}{}{\DeclareMathSymbol{I}{\mathalpha}{extraitalic}{138}}
tex/latex/arev/arevmath.sty:\ifthenelse{\equal{\var@f}  {true}}{}{\DeclareMathSymbol{f}{\mathalpha}{extraitalic}{154}}
tex/latex/arev/arevmath.sty:\ifthenelse{\equal{\var@l}  {true}}{}{\DeclareMathSymbol{l}{\mathalpha}{extraitalic}{141}}
tex/latex/arev/arevmath.sty:\ifthenelse{\equal{\var@u}  {true}}{}{\DeclareMathSymbol{u}{\mathalpha}{extraitalic}{142}}
tex/latex/arev/arevmath.sty:\ifthenelse{\equal{\var@v}  {true}}{}{\DeclareMathSymbol{v}{\mathalpha}{extraitalic}{143}}
tex/latex/arev/arevmath.sty:\ifthenelse{\equal{\var@w}  {true}}{}{\DeclareMathSymbol{w}{\mathalpha}{extraitalic}{144}}
tex/latex/arev/arevmath.sty:\ifthenelse{\equal{\var@x}  {true}}{}{\DeclareMathSymbol{x}{\mathalpha}{extraitalic}{145}}
tex/latex/arev/arevmath.sty:\DeclareMathSymbol{\origIota}{\mathord}{extraitalic}{30} % same as \origI
tex/latex/arev/arevmath.sty:\DeclareMathSymbol{\varIota}{\mathord}{extraitalic}{138} % same as \varI
```

and the first line,

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{extraitalic}      {U}{zavm}{m}{it}
```

was the one I was looking for.

Comment: That's awesome and exactly what I wanted--I am wondering, though, how you knew to use `extraitalic` and the other options? Were those specified in the `arevmath` style file and that was the key to what you did above (because I actually did look at the style file, but I was unsure of how to use the information there).

Comment: @FlintLockwood suing `\xfonttable` from the `fonttable` package you can get the information you required: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fonttable}
\usepackage{arevmath}
\begin{document}
\xfonttable{U}{zavm}{m}{it}

\xfonttable{U}{matha}{m}{n}

\end{document}`.

Comment: @FlintLockwood See edit for my approach which doesn't require me to know that the font family is `zavm`!

Comment: @GonzaloMedina But you have to know the name of the font family first in that case....

Comment: @cfr True. But I first looked into `arevmath.sty`,  so the name popped out immediately.

Comment: @FlintLockwood you can read `arevmath.sty` and recognize the symbol what you want (searching the command for the symbol is .sty file), then add the definition to your tex file. Run your code and this show an error: The font is not loaded. Then, you can recognize the font `extraitalic` to load. Write in console `grep extraitalic tex/latex/arev/*.sty`. The same process is for another symbol and another package, just make the appropiate changes.

Comment: Thank you for expanding your answer! The explanation makes a lot more sense in light of the other links I read before asking this question.

Comment: @FlintLockwood You're welcome. (And you're right: it isn't a complete standalone explanation. But I'm not sure that's doable in a single answer!)