# Importing accents and wide accents

Tags: fonts, accents, import, mathabx

I know how to import a single symbol from a different font ([Importing single symbol from MnSymbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36006/how-can-i-use-a-symbol-provided-by-a-package-without-changing-the-entire-mathema)), but it is possible to import an accent?

For example, I would like import `\underbrace` and `\widetilde` from `\usepackage{mathabx}`

Comment: In general it is a bad idea to replace parts of your fonts as they were designed to be coherent.  The idea of loading symbols from another math font is thought for amending symbols that are missing.  An example would be upright lowercase Greek letters, which are not part of Computer Modern.

Comment: Relevant to wide tilde: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63545/big-tilde-in-math-mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I copied the relevant definitions from `mathabx.sty` and `mathabx.dcl`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{
      <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10>
      <10.95> <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88>
      mathx10
      }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}

%%%%%%%%%
% Tilde %
%%%%%%%%%
\DeclareMathAccent{\widetilde}{0}{mathx}{"72}

%%%%%%%%%%
% Braces %
%%%%%%%%%%
\DeclareMathSymbol{\braceld}{0}{mathx}{"68}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bracemd}{0}{mathx}{"69}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bracerd}{0}{mathx}{"6A}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bracexd}{0}{mathx}{"6B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bracelu}{0}{mathx}{"6C}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bracemu}{0}{mathx}{"6D}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\braceru}{0}{mathx}{"6E}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bracexu}{0}{mathx}{"6F}

\def\braceexwd{2mu}
\def\bracevkern{0pt}

\def\bracefill#1#2#3#4{$\m@th
    #1#4\mkern-\braceexwd \cleaders\hbox{$#4$}\hfill
    \mkern-\braceexwd#4#2#4\mkern-\braceexwd
    \cleaders\hbox{$#4$}\hfill \mkern-\braceexwd#4#3$}

\def\overbrace@#1#2{\mathop{\vbox{\m@th\ialign{##\crcr
    \noalign{\kern\bracevkern}
    #1\crcr\noalign{\kern\bracevkern\nointerlineskip}
    $\hfil\displaystyle{#2}\hfil$\crcr}}}\limits}

\def\underbrace@#1#2{\mathop{\vtop{\m@th\ialign{##\crcr
    $\hfil\displaystyle{#2}\hfil$\crcr
    \noalign{\kern\bracevkern\nointerlineskip}
    #1\crcr\noalign{\kern\bracevkern}}}}\limits}

\def\overbrace{\overbrace@{\bracefill\braceld\bracemd\bracerd\bracexd}}
\def\underbrace{\underbrace@{\bracefill\bracelu\bracemu\braceru\bracexu}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
$\underbrace{\widetilde{a+b+c}}$
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so it should only import symbols?