# How to use only \diamondplus and \diamonddot from MnSymbol?

Tags: mnsymbol

Can you please post the specific code for using \diamondplus and \diamonddot from MnSymbol without loading this package?

The answer to the question [Importing single symbol from MnSymbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36006/importing-single-symbol-from-mnsymbol) gives a general procedure. To implement this procedure for a specific symbol different from the symbol used there requires understanding of [fntguide](http://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/fntguide.pdf) document. For those who do not understand fntguide, help asked here is essential. Also, more specific examples can help others gain better understanding of the general method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't known whether or not this makes sense, but you may copy the relevant code from `MnSymbol.sty` (and minimize it somehow), e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{MnSymbolC}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{MnSyC}{U}{MnSymbolC}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\diamondplus}{\mathbin}{MnSyC}{"7C}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\diamonddot}{\mathbin}{MnSyC}{"7E}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolC}{m}{n}{
    <-6>  MnSymbolC5
   <6-7>  MnSymbolC6
   <7-8>  MnSymbolC7
   <8-9>  MnSymbolC8
   <9-10> MnSymbolC9
  <10-12> MnSymbolC10
  <12->   MnSymbolC12}{}

\begin{document}
$\diamondplus \diamonddot$
\end{document}
```

[image: diamondplus and diamonddot]

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I need and it works perfectly.

Comment: Where do you find the LaTeX chart for this symbol?