# Correct diameter symbol needed without stix package (pdflatex)

Tags: pdftex, symbols, unicode, stix

I have drawn a custom diameter symbol in TikZ and now I need the correct unicode glyph (`U+2300` `⌀`) in my document (pdftex) to provide the right copy-paste text in the pdf. I've found that the `\diameter` symbol from the `stix` package produces the right glyph (testable at [fileformat.info](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm), it should say "DIAMETER SIGN" as the only result), but in my document `stix`  produces many errors (`Too many symbol fonts declared. ...ont{arrows2} {LS1}{stixsf} {m}{it}`) for which I wasn't able to find a fix.

So, how can I get the needed unicode glyph in my document with pdftex without using `stix`? No other symbol package I've tested produces the right glyph.

edit: I've looked into `stix.sty` and tried to use the definition from there, but this creates the wrong symbol ...

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\diam}{\mathord}{symbols}{"60}
\begin{document}
\(\diam\) % should always produce U+2300 
\end{document}
```

[image]

[This answer might apply here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36088/75284), but I couldn't get it to work for me.

Comment: Maybe you can provide a minimal but complete code example.

Comment: @Dr. Manuel Kuehner: Done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to set up a math font for just one symbol.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareFontEncoding{LS1}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS1}{stix}{m}{n}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\diameter}{%
  \text{\usefont{LS1}{stixscr}{m}{n}\symbol{"60}}%
}

\begin{document}
\(\diameter\) % something producing the U+2300 glyph
\end{document}
```

[image]

If I copy from the PDF and paste it in http://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/ I get

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Time for me to educate myself more on the topic instead of bothering others.

Comment: @lblb Oh, don't worry! It's fun to do these chores! `;-)`