# Importing single symbol from FdSymbol

Tags: fonts, luatex

I have tried to follow the instructions in

[Importing single symbol from MnSymbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36006/importing-single-symbol-from-mnsymbol)

in order to load a single symbol from the FdSymbol list without having to load the entire package (due to conflicting symbols), but I have been unsuccessful in adapting them to the FdSymbol package.  I would like to add the `\rightharpoonup` symbol (since the FdSymbol package provides a wider version of `\rightharpoonup` that the standard font).

I would appreciate any help in providing this single symbol from the FdSymbol package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{FdSymbolC}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{FdSymbolC}{m}{n}{<-> s * FdSymbolC-Book}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{fdarrows}{U}{FdSymbolC}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rightharpoonup}{\mathrel}{fdarrows}{"40}

\begin{document}

$\rightharpoonup$

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need the bold version as well, add

```
\DeclareFontShape{U}{FdSymbolC}{b}{n}{<-> s * FdSymbolC-Medium}{}
\SetSymbolFont{fdarrows}{bold}{U}{FdSymbolC}{b}{n}
```

Comment: How can I generate a table of the codes for each symbol provided by FdSymbol?

Comment: @TroyHenderson `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fdsymbol}
\usepackage{fonttable}
\begin{document}
\xfonttable{U}{FdSymbolC}{m}{n}
\end{document}`