# \medtriangleup etc from fdsymbol package

Tags: symbols, packages, import

I would like to import the equilateral triangle symbols `\medtriangleup`, `\medtriangleright`, `\medtriangleleft`, `\medtriangledown` from the `fdsymbol` package, without it screwing up `\nabla` and changing it into a big black dot.

I've found [similar answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398870/importing-single-symbol-from-fdsymbol)  [about importing symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499803/how-to-import-a-few-symbols-from-fdsymbol) from this package but I'm having trouble parsing the information to work out how to adapt it for my needs.

Can anyone point me towards any relevant documentation or help me understand what the steps involved are for my particular task?

Or, a workaround, does anyone know a package with nice-looking triangles like those found in `fdsymbol`, that I can import without messing up `\nabla`??

Comment: The `unicode-math`, `stix` and `stix2` packages are especially comprehensive.

Comment: Do you mean `fdsymbol`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file `fdsymbol.sty` defines all symbols sequentially and one has to count lines or exploit some other trick: `fonttable` is our friend.

First of all, look for `\medtriangleright`, to find

```
\fdsy@DeclareSymbol{\medtriangleright}{symbols}{\mathbin}
  \fdsy@DeclareAlias{\triangleright}{symbols}{\mathbin}
\fdsy@DeclareSymbol{\medtriangleup}{symbols}{\mathbin}
  \fdsy@DeclareAlias{\triangle}{symbols}{\mathbin}
  \fdsy@DeclareAlias{\vartriangle}{symbols}{\mathbin}
\fdsy@DeclareSymbol{\medtriangleleft}{symbols}{\mathbin}
  \fdsy@DeclareAlias{\triangleleft}{symbols}{\mathbin}
\fdsy@DeclareSymbol{\medtriangledown}{symbols}{\mathbin}
  \fdsy@DeclareAlias{\triangledown}{symbols}{\mathbin}
```

so we know that we need the `symbols` math font:

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbols}{U}{FdSymbolA}{m}{n}
```

OK, look for `FdSymbolA`

```
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{FdSymbolA}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{FdSymbolA}{m}{n}{
    <-7.1> s * [\fdsy@scale] FdSymbolA-\fdsy@mweight@small
    <7.1-> s * [\fdsy@scale] FdSymbolA-\fdsy@mweight@normal
}{}
```

Now it's apparent that `\fdsy@scale` is a scale factor; use 1 to begin the study; what are the other commands? They depend on options given to the package:

```
\fdsy@choicekey{normalweight}{book,regular,auto}{%
  \ifcase\@tempb\relax
    \renewcommand\fdsy@mweight@normal{Book}%
    \renewcommand\fdsy@mweight@small{Book}%
  \or
    \renewcommand\fdsy@mweight@normal{Regular}%
    \renewcommand\fdsy@mweight@small{Regular}%
  \or
    \renewcommand\fdsy@mweight@normal{Book}%
    \renewcommand\fdsy@mweight@small{Regular}%
  \fi
}
```

I'd go with the `book` choice. So we can start:

```
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{FdSymbolA}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{FdSymbolA}{m}{n}{
    <-7.1> s * [1] FdSymbolA-Book
    <7.1-> s * [1] FdSymbolA-Book
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{fdsymbols}{U}{FdSymbolA}{m}{n}
```

One *must* use a different name than `symbols`.

Oh, well, there's no point in separating the fonts, so we can do

```
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{FdSymbolA}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{FdSymbolA}{m}{n}{
    <-> s * [1] FdSymbolA-Book
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{fdsymbols}{U}{FdSymbolA}{m}{n}
```

Now we need to define the symbols and we need to find the slots. It's not really difficult: make a simple file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fonttable}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{FdSymbolA}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{FdSymbolA}{m}{n}{
    <-> s * [1] FdSymbolA-Book
}{}

\begin{document}

\xfonttable{U}{FdSymbolA}{m}{n}

\end{document}
```

and run LaTeX on it. You'll find the symbols laid out with codes!

[image]

Now we can finish up.

```
\documentclass{article}

%%% define symbols from fdsymbol
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{FdSymbolA}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{FdSymbolA}{m}{n}{
    <-> s * [1] FdSymbolA-Book
}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{FdSymbolA}{m}{b}{
    <-> s * [1] FdSymbolA-Medium
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{fdsymbols}{U}{FdSymbolA}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{fdsymbols}{bold}{U}{FdSymbolA}{m}{b}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\medtriangleright}{\mathbin}{fdsymbols}{86}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\medtriangleup}{\mathbin}{fdsymbols}{87}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\medtriangleleft}{\mathbin}{fdsymbols}{88}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\medtriangledown}{\mathbin}{fdsymbols}{89}
%%%

\begin{document}

$a\medtriangleright b\medtriangleup c\medtriangleleft d \medtriangledown e$

\boldmath

$a\medtriangleright b\medtriangleup c\medtriangleleft d \medtriangledown e$

\end{document}
```

Test with different scale factors until you're satisfied. I added support for bold math.

[image]

Just for completeness, here's the output with `[1]` changed into `[0.8]` to get reduced size for the symbols:

```
\DeclareFontShape{U}{FdSymbolA}{m}{n}{
    <-> s * [0.8] FdSymbolA-Book
}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{FdSymbolA}{m}{b}{
    <-> s * [0.8] FdSymbolA-Medium
}{}
```

(no other change).

[image]

Comment: Very helpful! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The `unicode-math`, `stix` and `stix2` packages have all of these, but the official names are not very consistent.  A MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[
  range ={ \bigtriangleup, \bigtriangledown, \triangleleft, \triangleright,
           \vartriangle, \triangledown, \smalltriangleleft, \smalltriangleright },
  Scale = MatchUppercase ]

\begin{document}
Triangles: \( \bigtriangleup \bigtriangledown \triangleleft \triangleright
              \vartriangle \triangledown \smalltriangleleft \smalltriangleright
              \nabla \increment \Delta \)
\end{document}
```

[image: STIX Two Math sample]

The command to import these symbols from `fdsymbol` (which I did here with their standard names and math classes) is more complex.  The package is not set up to make it easy to copy and paste only a piece of it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{FdSymbolA}{}

\DeclareFontShape{U}{FdSymbolA}{m}{n}{
  <-7.1> s * [1.0] FdSymbolA-Book
  <7.1-> s * [1.0] FdSymbolA-Book
}{}

\DeclareFontShape{U}{FdSymbolA}{b}{n}{
  <-7.1> s * [1.0] FdSymbolA-Bold
  <7.1-> s * [1.0] FdSymbolA-Bold
}{}

\DeclareSymbolFont{fdsymbols}{U}{FdSymbolA}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{fdsymbols}{bold}{U}{FdSymbolA}{b}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\vartriangle}{\mathbin}{fdsymbols}{87}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\triangledown}{\mathord}{fdsymbols}{89}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\smalltriangleleft}{\mathbin}{fdsymbols}{88}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\smalltriangleright}{\mathbin}{fdsymbols}{86}

\begin{document}

Triangles: \( \vartriangle \triangledown \smalltriangleleft \smalltriangleright
              \nabla \Delta \)

\end{document}
```

[image: fdsymbol sample]

You can, if you prefer, change the lines like

```
<-7.1> s * [1.0] FdSymbolA-Book
```

to change the scale parameter `[1.0]` or set the `m` weight to `FdSymbolA-Regular` and the `b` weight to `FdSymbolA-Medium`, and get the same effect as the package options to `fdsymbol`.

Comment: The first method seems the most straightforward but a warning for future readers: unicode-math doesn't play well with pdfLaTeX.

Comment: @jms547 I’ve added a sentence about that, in case anyone here doesn’t already know.

Answer (score 2):

Everything is in the [documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/fdsymbol) of `fdsymbol`, but indeed if you have never read the source files of a font package you might have a hard time trying to understand what's going on.

Here's an example to load only the commands you want from `fdsymbol`. I simply took the relevant definitions from the source files. The output is the four triangle symbols, and a `\nabla` to verify it has not changed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{FdSymbolA}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{FdSymbolA}{m}{n}{
    <-7.1> FdSymbolA-Book
    <7.1-> FdSymbolA-Book
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{FdSymbols}{U}{FdSymbolA}{m}{n}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\fdsy@nextslot{\advance\@tempcnta 1\relax}
\newcommand\fdsy@@DeclareSymbol[4]{\DeclareMathSymbol{#2}{#3}{#4}{#1}}
\newcommand\fdsy@DeclareSymbol[3]{%
    \if\relax\noexpand#1\let#1\undefined\fi
    \expandafter\fdsy@@DeclareSymbol\expandafter{\the\@tempcnta}{#1}{#3}{#2}%
    \fdsy@nextslot
}
\@tempcnta 86
\fdsy@DeclareSymbol{\medtriangleright}{FdSymbols}{\mathbin}
\fdsy@DeclareSymbol{\medtriangleup}{FdSymbols}{\mathbin}
\fdsy@DeclareSymbol{\medtriangleleft}{FdSymbols}{\mathbin}
\fdsy@DeclareSymbol{\medtriangledown}{FdSymbols}{\mathbin}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\(\medtriangleright\medtriangleup\medtriangleleft\medtriangledown\nabla\)
\end{document}
```