# Importing \bigplus and \bigtimes from mathabx package

Tags: symbols, packages, import

Similar to [my question here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/574360/medtriangleup-etc-from-fdsymbol-package): I want to import `\bigplus` and `\bigtimes` from the `mathabx` package but not use the whole package as it alters the look of `\int, \partial` etc.

There are a lot of solutions out there for similar problems but I don't know where to start adapting them to my own needs as they seem like magic LaTeX incantations! Can anyone give me a  particular solution, or help me understand how to adopt a general solution?

If possible I would like to avoid relying on the `amsmath` package because the journal class file I'm using does not play well with `amsmath` (very frustrating but I cannot do anything about this!).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do it:

```
\documentclass{article}%

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{
<-6> mathx5 <6-7> mathx6 <7-8> matha7
<8-9> mathx8 <9-10> mathx9
<10-12> mathx10 <12-> mathx12
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bigplus}{\mathop}{mathx}{"90}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bigtimes}{\mathop}{mathx}{"91}

\begin{document}

\[ A \bigplus B \qquad C\bigtimes D\]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bernard and Steven B Segletes. I went with Bernard's answer in the end because the symbols were a bit too big in Steven's answer.

But can you help me understand what the difference between your answers is? As far as I can see, the only differences are the slots in `\DelareMathSymbol`, i.e. `"90, "91"` (Bernard) vs `"A0, "A1` (Steven), and the numbers in `\DeclareFontShape`. So what do these numbers in `\DeclareFontShape` mean and do?

Comment: As far as I remember (I've adapted an old answer for another symbol), `mathx cjhooses automatically the glyph in the correct slot, according to the required font size. The numbers denote the position of the glyph in the font table, in base 16 with the double quote. Base  8 can also be used  if the single quote is used.

Comment: ok, thanks. What about the other strange incantation in the line
`\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{
<-6> mathx5 <6-7> mathx6 <7-8> matha7
<8-9> mathx8 <9-10> mathx9
<10-12> mathx10 <12-> mathx12
}{}`
?

Comment: This is, as far as I remember, because the font exists in several base sizes, and it tells the compiler which base size to use depending on the required size in the document (it is the font which contains the variable size delimiters).

Answer (score 2):

I include the `mathabx` font tables at the end, so that you can see that the `\bigplus` and `\bigtimes` are part of the the `mathx` subset of `mathabx`, occupying slots "A0 and "A1.

```
\documentclass{article}
% Setup the mathx font (from mathxbx.sty)
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{
      <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10> gen * mathx
      <10.95> mathx10 <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88> mathx12
      }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}

% Define a subset character from that font (from mathabx.dcl)

\DeclareMathSymbol{\bigplus}{1}{mathx}{"A0}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bigtimes}{1}{mathx}{"A1}

\usepackage{fonttable}
\begin{document}

\texttt{mathabx} subset

\[
A \bigtimes B
\]
\[
B \bigplus A
\]

\tiny\clearpage
\fonttable{mathx10}\clearpage
\fonttable{matha10}\clearpage
\fonttable{mathb10}
\end{document}
```

[image]