# Symbol(enter symbol)

Tags: symbols

Is there a latex symbol for this ↵ but pointing towards the right?

I have found none even after looking at this website
https://latex-tutorial.com/arrow-latex/

Comment: Maybe a ```\reflectbox{}``` could be helpful.

Comment: Did you check the [Comprehensive List](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf)?

Comment: Found it @JasperHabicht, Thanks!
Table 147 - mathabx arrow
\drsh

Comment: The problem with loading `mathabx` is that it changes most of the default math symbols, which may not be your desire.  See, for example, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176941/conflict-between-mathabx-and-other-packages and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/586507/importing-bigplus-and-bigtimes-from-mathabx-package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{boisik}
\DeclareSymbolFont{bskarr}{U}{bskarr}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{bskarr}{ }
\DeclareFontShape{U}{bskarr}{m}{n}{<->bskarr10}{}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\drsh}{\mathrel}{bskarr}{"F9}
\begin{document}
$\drsh$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or, one could build it from scratch:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx}
\newcommand\drsh{\mathop{\ensurestackMath{%
  \stackengine{-1.2pt}{\rightarrow}{\scalebox{1}[.35]{%
    $\mkern-1.3mu\vert$}}{O}{l}{F}{F}{S}}}}
\begin{document}
$A\drsh B$
\end{document}
```

[image]