# Borrow symbols with style

Tags: fonts, mnsymbol

This [example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36088) shows know how to import a symbol from `MnSymbol`. I find the code quite long and complex and wonder if some more elegant way exist. Also, possibly, a way that does not require “wasting a precious math alphabet resource”.

This [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14406) suggests one (though not applied to `MnSymbol`). AFAIU this alternative approach is especially well suited when the font “provides `.fd` files”. What does that mean? Does `MnSymbol` provide `.fd` files? Otherwise, how hard would it be to create those files, so that symbols can be imported using fewer lines of code? In which cases should one use the `pifont` approach to import fonts, rather than the one that does not use any package (illustrated in my first link)?

Is there another package that is especially suited to import symbols? This [FAQ](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-usesymb) recommends [yagusylo](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/yagusylo), but it hasn’t been updated since 2009 and does not seem to be much [used](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=yagusylo).

I am especially interested in importing from `MnSymbol`, and more specifically, importing symbols such as `\ntriplesim`, `\nlessgtr`, `\ngtreqlessslant` and the like, but if this question can be answered in general (for any font), the better, of course.

Comment: Can you tell about what symbols you'd like to import?

Comment: in the first reference you cite, it says that `MnSymbol` does *not* provide `.fd` files, but defines all the information usually found in `.fd` files instead in the `.sty` file.  it should not be difficult to extract that into `.fd` files, using as a model the method used for `mathabx`.  but that certainly wouldn't avoid "wasting a precious math alphabet resource".

Comment: @egreg I added examples of specific symbols I’m interested in.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the three symbols you mention:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\frommnsymbol}[3]{%
  %1 = atom type, #2 = mnsymbol font, #3 = character
  #1{\text{\usefont{U}{MnSymbol#2}{m}{n}\symbol{#3}}}%
}

%\DeclareFontFamily{U}{MnSymbolA}{}
%\DeclareFontFamily{U}{MnSymbolB}{}
%\DeclareFontFamily{U}{MnSymbolC}{}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{MnSymbolD}{}
%\DeclareFontFamily{U}{MnSymbolF}{}

%\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolA}{m}{n}{
%    <-6>  MnSymbolA5
%   <6-7>  MnSymbolA6
%   <7-8>  MnSymbolA7
%   <8-9>  MnSymbolA8
%   <9-10> MnSymbolA9
%  <10-12> MnSymbolA10
%  <12->   MnSymbolA12}{}
%\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolB}{m}{n}{
%    <-6>  MnSymbolB5
%   <6-7>  MnSymbolB6
%   <7-8>  MnSymbolB7
%   <8-9>  MnSymbolB8
%   <9-10> MnSymbolB9
%  <10-12> MnSymbolB10
%  <12->   MnSymbolB12}{}
%\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolC}{m}{n}{
%    <-6>  MnSymbolC5
%   <6-7>  MnSymbolC6
%   <7-8>  MnSymbolC7
%   <8-9>  MnSymbolC8
%   <9-10> MnSymbolC9
%  <10-12> MnSymbolC10
%  <12->   MnSymbolC12}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolD}{m}{n}{
    <-6>  MnSymbolD5
   <6-7>  MnSymbolD6
   <7-8>  MnSymbolD7
   <8-9>  MnSymbolD8
   <9-10> MnSymbolD9
  <10-12> MnSymbolD10
  <12->   MnSymbolD12}{}
%\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolF}{m}{n}{
%    <-6>  MnSymbolF5
%   <6-7>  MnSymbolF6
%   <7-8>  MnSymbolF7
%   <8-9>  MnSymbolF8
%   <9-10> MnSymbolF9
%  <10-12> MnSymbolF10
%  <12->   MnSymbolF12}{}

\newcommand{\ntriplesim}{\frommnsymbol{\mathrel}{D}{"7E}}
\newcommand{\nlessgtr}{\frommnsymbol{\mathrel}{D}{"C0}}
\newcommand{\ngtreqlessslant}{\frommnsymbol{\mathrel}{D}{"C7}}

\begin{document}

$a\ntriplesim b$ $a\nlessgtr b$ $a\ngtreqlessslant b$

$X_{a\ntriplesim b}$ $X_{a\nlessgtr b}$ $X_{a\ngtreqlessslant b}$

\end{document}
```

I commented out the unused fonts.

The font declarations are directly borrowed from `MnSymbol.sty`. How are the letter and code determined?

I looked in `MnSymbol.sty` for the three symbols

```
\Decl@Mn@Char\ntriplesim             {MnSyD}{\mathrel}
\Decl@Mn@Char\nlessgtr               {MnSyD}{\mathrel}
\Decl@Mn@Char\ngtreqlessslant        {MnSyD}{\mathrel}
```

This determines the letter to use. Unfortunately, `MnSymbol` doesn't use explicit codes for the symbols, but there's a trick for getting them without counting in the file: `latexdef -p MnSymbol` followed by the symbols' names will show the necessary codes.

```
> latexdef -p MnSymbol ntriplesim nlessgtr ngtreqlessslant

\ntriplesim:
\mathchar"377E

\the\ntriplesim:
14206

\nlessgtr:
\mathchar"37C0

\the\nlessgtr:
14272

\ngtreqlessslant:
\mathchar"37C7

\the\ngtreqlessslant:
14279
```

Thus I can supply as character code the last two digit in the `\mathchar` representation.