# Symbol $\perp$ with a shorter horizontal line to be used as a superscript

Tags: math-mode, symbols, typography, superscripts

i was wondering whether there exists a predefined Latex symbol or command to write $\perp$ with a shorter horizontal line as shown in the image below which has been taken from an old research article in fluid mechanics. In fact, i would like to use that as a superscript liekwise.

Any help or idea is highly appreciated. Thank you

[image: Example symbol taken from literature]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The version of `\perp` in the [MnSymbol package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/MnSymbol) is narrower than the 'standard' version, but also slightly shorter. To load it without changing lots of other things, we can borrow most of the code from @Leo Liu's answer to [Importing single symbol from MnSymbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36006/2417). Then we obtain the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareFontFamily{U} {MnSymbolA}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolA}{m}{n}{
  <-6> MnSymbolA5
  <6-7> MnSymbolA6
  <7-8> MnSymbolA7
  <8-9> MnSymbolA8
  <9-10> MnSymbolA9
  <10-12> MnSymbolA10
  <12-> MnSymbolA12}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolA}{b}{n}{
  <-6> MnSymbolA-Bold5
  <6-7> MnSymbolA-Bold6
  <7-8> MnSymbolA-Bold7
  <8-9> MnSymbolA-Bold8
  <9-10> MnSymbolA-Bold9
  <10-12> MnSymbolA-Bold10
  <12-> MnSymbolA-Bold12}{}

\DeclareSymbolFont{MnSyA} {U} {MnSymbolA}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\mnperp}{\mathrel}{MnSyA}{217}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{ll}
\perp & \mnperp \\ \mnperp &
\end{array}
\quad
 A^\perp \quad A^\mnperp
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: perp symbols]

Comment: Thanks for your great answer!

Answer (score 8):

Adjust to suit:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,l3draw,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\sperp}{}
 {% short perp
  {\mathord{\text{\daddy_sperp:}}}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \daddy_sperp:
 {
  \use:c { check@mathfonts }
  $\mspace{1mu}$
  \draw_begin:
  \draw_cap_round: % good for CM fonts
  \draw_linewidth:n { \dim_to_fp:n { \fontdimen8\textfont2 }/18 } % thickness of the fraction line
  \draw_path_moveto:n { 0em, 0ex }
  \draw_path_lineto:n { 0.3em, 0ex }
  \draw_path_use:n { stroke }
  \draw_path_moveto:n { 0.15em, 0ex }
  \draw_path_lineto:n { 0.15em, 1.3ex }
  \draw_path_use:n { stroke }
  \draw_end:
  $\mspace{1mu}$
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$A^{\sperp}_n$ $\perp\sperp\scriptstyle\sperp\scriptscriptstyle\sperp$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why the `daddy` name? Lol

Comment: @manooooh I mostly use the OP's nickname as prefix.

Answer (score 6):

Works in all math styles...can easily choose scale by changing Vert/Horz. stretch parameters shown as `.6` and `.5`.  Line thicknesses will always be good, since this is composed from an overlay of `-` and `\vert` in the appropriate math style.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\newcommand\newperp{\mathbin{\ThisStyle{\setbox0=\hbox{%
  \abovebaseline[-\dimexpr.5\LMex+.2ex]{%
  \ensurestackMath{\stackengine{-\dimexpr.6\LMex+.2ex}%
  {\SavedStyle\hstretch{.6}{-}}% ADJUSTABLE V SCALE
  {\SavedStyle\vstretch{.5}{\vert}}% ADJUSTABLE H SCALE
  {O}{c}{F}{F}{S}}}}\dp0=0pt\box0}}}
\begin{document} 

$A\newperp B$
$\scriptstyle A\newperp B$
$\scriptscriptstyle A\newperp B$

$A^{\newperp}_n$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Changing stretches to .7/.6 changes result to

[image]