Extracting \downmapsto from MnSymbol
How do I extract the \downmapsto symbol from MnSymbol? I cannot use the entire package as it conflicts with other packages I am using. There are questions on here about extracting other symbols but I am a beginner with TeX and do not understand how to adapt those answers to my symbol.
Thank you in advance.

The easiest thing is probably to rotate \mapsto
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{drcutils,graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\downmapsto}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\down@mapsto\relax\mkern2mu}}
\newcommand*{\down@mapsto}[2]{\vcenter{\hbox{\rotatebox{-90}{\m@th$#1\mapsto$}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$a \downarrow b$\par
$a\downmapsto b$\par
$\scriptstyle a \downarrow b$\par
$\scriptstyle a \downmapsto b$\par
$\scriptscriptstyle a \downarrow b$\par
$\scriptscriptstyle a \downmapsto b$

\end{document}


The manual spacing of 2mu on the right is needed because \mapsto has a rather unsymmetrical bounding box. Alternatively, you can build the symbol from other existing ones:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}% for \dabar@

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\downmapsto}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\down@mapsto\relax}}
\newcommand*{\down@mapsto}[2]{%
   \vcenter{%
      \m@th
      \setbox\z@=\hbox{$#1\dabar@$}%
      \ialign{\hfil$#1##$\hfil\cr\noalign{\kern-.45\ht\z@}
         \copy\z@\cr\noalign{\nointerlineskip\kern-.55\ht\z@}
         \downarrow\cr
      }%
   }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$a \downarrow b \downmapsto c_{a \downarrow b \downmapsto c_{a \downarrow b \downmapsto c}}$

\end{document}


In the second case you don't have to guess the horizontal spacing, but the vertical one might still depend on the used font.

Thank you so much! I have no idea what the code does but it does exactly what I need.

@Anon \ialign is the low level way TeX uses to make tables. Basically I am stacking \dabar@ (a kind of short minus) on top of \downarrow. A couple of negative spacings are necessary for the two symbols to overlap correctly. And \mathpalette... well, that's going to be one of your best friends if you often make your own symbols. See The mysteries of \mathpalette for a description.

You could follow the guide from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36088/36296 and import the \downmapsto symbol like this:
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareFontFamily{U} {MnSymbolA}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolA}{m}{n}{
  <-6> MnSymbolA5
  <6-7> MnSymbolA6
  <7-8> MnSymbolA7
  <8-9> MnSymbolA8
  <9-10> MnSymbolA9
  <10-12> MnSymbolA10
  <12-> MnSymbolA12}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolA}{b}{n}{
  <-6> MnSymbolA-Bold5
  <6-7> MnSymbolA-Bold6
  <7-8> MnSymbolA-Bold7
  <8-9> MnSymbolA-Bold8
  <9-10> MnSymbolA-Bold9
  <10-12> MnSymbolA-Bold10
  <12-> MnSymbolA-Bold12}{}

\DeclareSymbolFont{MnSyA} {U} {MnSymbolA}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\downmapsto}{\mathrel}{MnSyA}{43}

\begin{document}

$\downmapsto$

\end{document}



I too tried this same way exactly, but I could not able to find 43 having this symbol, can you explain how you found 43 having the downmapsto symbol? Please.

@MadyYuvi The second to last code block in the linked tutorial shows how to produce a list with the symbol numbers.

Thanks a lot for the details

You might apply \mapstochar to a rotated \downarrow and the rotate the whole thing.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\downmapsto}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\down@mapsto\relax}}
\newcommand*{\down@mapsto}[2]{%
  \vcenter{%
    \m@th
    \hbox{%
      \rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{%
        $#1\mkern-1mu\mapstochar\mkern2mu$%
        \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$#1\downarrow$}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

{\fboxsep=0pt\fboxrule=0.1pt\fbox{$\downmapsto$}}

$a \downarrow b \downmapsto c_{a \downarrow b \downmapsto c_{a \downarrow b \downmapsto c}}$

$a \downmapsto b \downarrow c$

\end{document}



Thanks, that works too!
