How to rotate \mapsto so that it points upward?
I'd like to ask how to make a symbol like \mapsto but pointing upwards. (I'd like to use it as a relation to specify dummy variables in, for example, sums. Because of that, I wouldn't want for it to make other symbols further away from the bottom of the sum.) I was able to get a version of it working with
\newcommand{\upmapsto}{
  \,\mathrel{\raisebox{0.25ex}{\scalebox{1}[0.8]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\scaleobj{0.75}{\mapsto}$}}}}  
}

to get the following result.

However, I feel that the code might be over-engineered or produce some wrong results. (Essentially, I combined some solutions from the forum to get something that looks somewhat good, but I doubt that this is the preferred way.)

You could use a package like MnSymbol or fdsymbol, which provides such a symbol:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\begin{document}

\[
\upmapsto
\]


\end{document}


Both of these packages seem to work, but they also change some other symbols in my document. (I added some math alphabets which seems to create errors). Is there a way to add only one symbol from such a package?

@Kakuro See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36006/importing-single-symbol-from-mnsymbol and references therein on how to import individual symbols

Thank you --- this fully solves my problem

@Kakuro You're welcome!
