# How to get bigsqcap in the right size

Tags: fonts, math-mode, symbols

I would like to use the upside-down version of `\bigsqcup` to denote its dual operation.
The `stmaryrd` package provides that symbol, `\bigsqcap`, but I have found that these two symbols are rendered in different sizes.

Below are sample code and its output.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\begin{document}
$\bigsqcup \bigsqcap \bigcup \bigcap$
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, `\bigsqcap` is clearly the odd one out, being slightly bigger than the rest.

Does anyone know how to get `\bigsqcap` in the same size as `\bigsqcup`?
I need to use the `mathptmx` font, so I would appreciate a solution that retains it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple solution is to rotate `\bigsqcup` to get the missing `\bigsqcap`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\providecommand{\bigsqcap}{%
  \mathop{%
    \mathpalette\@updown\bigsqcup
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\@updown}[2]{%
  \rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\m@th#1#2$}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[\bigsqcup \bigsqcap \bigcup \bigcap\]
\[X\bigsqcup_0^\infty Y \bigsqcap_0^\infty Z\]
\[\bigsqcup\textstyle\bigsqcup
  \scriptstyle\bigsqcup\scriptscriptstyle\bigsqcup\]
\[\bigsqcup\textstyle\bigsqcap
  \scriptstyle\bigsqcap\scriptscriptstyle\bigsqcap\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- The rotation switches to text mode (`\hbox`). `\mathpalette` is the method to get the current math style that we need, when we reenter math in the rotated box for `\bigsqcup`. The first argument of `\@updown` is the math style (`\displaystyle`, `\textstyle`, …), the second argument is the unrotated symbol. Thus `\@updown` can also be used for the rotation of other symbols.
- `\m@th` suppresses `\mathsurround` for the case this value is set to avoid that space that should surround math formulas appears inside the formula.

Answer (score 5):

Use package `MnSymbol` instead of `stmaryrd`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\begin{document}
$\bigsqcup \bigsqcap \bigcup \bigcap$
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

Comment: beware -- `MnSymbol` redefines lots of other symbols, so it's advised to limit your use to just the symbols you need.  for tips on how to do so, see [how to use MnSymbol along with other packages](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17370/579) and [Discard symbols from package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12843/579)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Yes, I know that, but I like this package very much and I use it in conjuction with `amssymb`, too, despite they say they are not compatible!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This works, but I wanted to retain the mathptmx versions of \bigsqcup, \bigcup and \bigcap.

Comment: @Usagi That's OK. Note however that `\bigsqcup`, `\bigcup` and `\bigcap` don't come from `mathptmx` but are standard commands. Also, `MnSymbol` symbols are suitable for fonts like Times (as `mathptmx` uses) and Minion Pro...

Comment: I see. `mathptmx` wasn't really my personal choice, but something that I am asked to use. Otherwise, I might have used `MnSymbol`, since it does look nice.