# How to create up arrow with two heads?

Tags: math-mode, arrows

With `\twoheadrightarrow` we can get arrow with two heads. Is there any command for getting two heads with up arrow?

Comment: `\twoheaduparrow` from `MnSymbol` perhaps? `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda I love that package, but many people here seems to advise against its use...

Comment: @karlkoeller perhaps is not advise against its use, but to warn that it changes some symbols?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Yes, I'm aware of that, and that's why I like it. But why is it a so bad practice to change several symbols in your document? For example, see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/121727/27635) of mine. I prefer `MnSymbol` symbols at the default ones when using `mathptmx` package. Is it so strange (or even bad practice)?

Comment: @karlkoeller I wouldn't say it is a bad practice as long as consistency is guaranteed.

Comment: I had trouble with the MnSymbol package so this solution seems much easier from a compiling standpoint.

Answer (score 7):

One can rotate one of the existing two-headed arrows (some adjustment might be required depending on the desired position for the arrow baseline):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand\twoheaduparrow{\mathrel{\rotatebox{90}{$\twoheadrightarrow$}}}

\begin{document}

\[
A\twoheadrightarrow B\quad A\twoheaduparrow B
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Adding `[origin=<origin>]` as an option to `\rotate`, the center for rotation can be changed (possible values for `<origin>` are `t` (top),`b` (bottom),`l` (left),`r` (right),`c` (center), and `B` (baseline)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand\twoheaduparrow{\mathrel{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$\twoheadrightarrow$}}}

\begin{document}

\[
A\twoheadrightarrow B\quad A\twoheaduparrow B
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

In a comment it has been requested a definition without using additional packages; in this case, with a little more work, one can build the symbol using `\ooalign` and two shifted `\uparrow`s:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\twoheaduparrow{%
\mathrel{\mathchoice
  {\raise2pt\hbox{%
  \ooalign{\hss$\uparrow$\hss\cr\lower2pt\hbox{%
  $\uparrow$}}}}
  {\raise2pt\hbox{%
  \ooalign{\hss$\uparrow$\hss\cr\lower2pt\hbox{%
  $\uparrow$}}}}
  {\raise1.5pt\hbox{%
  \ooalign{\hss$\scriptstyle\uparrow$\hss\cr\lower1.5pt\hbox{%
  $\scriptstyle\uparrow$}}}}
  {\raise1.1pt\hbox{%
  \ooalign{\hss$\scriptscriptstyle\uparrow$\hss\cr\lower1.1pt\hbox{%
  $\scriptscriptstyle\uparrow$}}}}
}}

\begin{document}

\[
A\twoheaduparrow B\quad {\textstyle A\twoheaduparrow B}\quad A_{A\twoheaduparrow B}\quad L_{A_{A\twoheaduparrow B}}
\]

\[
A\uparrow B\quad {\textstyle A\uparrow B}\quad A_{A\uparrow B}\quad L_{A_{A\uparrow B}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i'd have assumed that the arrow should be aligned vertically around the math axis.  to do that, all that's necessary is to add an option to the rotation: `\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{...}`

Comment: @barbarabeeton yes; I mentioned that some adjustments might be needed, depending on the desired alignment. I've added to my answer an example with `origin=c` as you suggested.

Comment: How about if one cannot use graphicx package? Is there any straight forward way to use it? Looks like this symbol is not in amssymb.

Comment: @manjusha Why wouldn't one be allowed to use `graphicx`? The symbols is not predefined in `amssymb` (there's a `\twoheaduparrow` in the `MnSymbol` package, but `MnSymbol` changes the look of many other symbols). In any case, I've updated my answer with a definition of the symbol not requiring additional packages.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, actually while converting the tex file to other web supported formats  with such user defined commands there need more  server side configurations. Which I am trying to avoid.

Comment: In  general if `\twoheadleftarrow` and `\twoheadrightarrow` is in `amssymb`. Then is'nt it easy to have two more commands with `\twoheaduparrow` and `\twoheaddownarrow` in `amssymb`?

Comment: @manjusha that is a question you should ask to the maintainers of the AMS packages. You can contact them using `tech-support@ams.org`.

Answer (score 4):

The gap between arrow heads is set at `.3\arrowheight` and can be changed.  Of note in this solution is the `\ThisStyle{...\SavedStyle...}` construct which allows the current (at invocation) math style to be imported into places where it would otherwise be lost.

That feature allows a four-pronged `\mathchoice` to be replaced with a single `\ThisStyle{}` (of course, the `\mathchoice` resides within `\ThisStyle`, but it sure saves on typing).  And because I defined the arrow gap (`.3\arrowheight`) in terms of the length of the current mathstyle arrow, I didn't need to apply different stackgaps (i.e., arrowhead shift lengths) for each mathstyle.  Furthermore, using the arrow height itself to define the magnitude of the shift means that this solution works just fine if presented in `\Huge`.  Other solutions will not hold up so well.

As a final note, this solution preserves the baseline of the original `\uparrow`, which a rotated-arrow solution will not do without further manipulation.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newlength\arrowheight
\newcommand\doubleuparrow{%
  \mathrel{\ThisStyle{%
    \setlength{\arrowheight}{\heightof{$\SavedStyle\uparrow$}}%
    \stackengine{.3\arrowheight}{$\SavedStyle\uparrow$}%
      {$\SavedStyle\uparrow$}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}}
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
A \doubleuparrow C \quad A_{A \doubleuparrow C}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**SUPPLEMENT**

A commenter asks if the vertical size can be made to match the normal `\uparrow`.  One *could* clip the bottom.  However, here, I choose to scale down the result to the same height as the `\uparrow`.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newlength\arrowheight
\newcommand\doubleuparrow{%
  \mathrel{\ThisStyle{%
    \setlength{\arrowheight}{\heightof{$\SavedStyle\uparrow$}}%
    \scalerel*{\stackengine{.3\arrowheight}{$\SavedStyle\uparrow$}%
      {$\SavedStyle\uparrow$}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}}{\uparrow}}
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
A \uparrow \doubleuparrow C \quad A_{A \uparrow \doubleuparrow C}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If one would prefer a *stretch* to a *scale*, just substitute `\stretchrel` for `\scalerel`, to get

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to downsize this so it looks good next to a single-head arrow?  $\doubleuparrow$ is taller than $\uparrow$.

Comment: @CharlesRezk Please see the **SUPPLEMENT** to my answer.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll note this looks as desired when using pdflatex, but not in a .dvi file created from the same Tex.

Comment: @CharlesRezk When I try to compile a dvi, I get an error that some pdfspecials cannot be rendered.  However, I'm not sure what those specials woud be, since I don't recall either stackengine nor scalrel using pdfspecials.  Problem seems to arise with `scalerel` package.