# How to draw a surjective (double-headed) arrow between two nodes in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-arrows

I can't find how to draw a surjective arrow between two nodes in TikZ.
I'd like it to look somewhat like this.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! See: [How to create up arrow with two heads?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/122473/124842)

Answer (score 9):

A pure TikZ solution involves using `->>` and that's about it:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\node at (0,0) (a) {A};
\node at (1,0) (b) {B};
\path [draw,->>] (a) -- (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Quack]

And we are done. `:)`

Answer (score 3):

By importing `tikz-cd` package, you can use `\arrow` command with `twoheadrightarrow` option as follows:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd} 
A \arrow[r, tail, twoheadrightarrow, dashed] & B
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

My further proposal would be to use, as an alternative, the `xy` package. You get the same results as in the previous answers.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[cmtip,all]{xy}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix@C=1.5pc{A\ar@{->>}[r]& B
}
\end{document}
```